# How to prevent PhpStorm to save file on exit without prompt?

Tags: php, editor, phpstorm

Consider this situation...You're just making changes to few files at once. The code isn't completed yet and the phone is ringing...  Then you have to close PhpStorm, turn off your computer and hurry because something important happened.
Then after one week you'll come back, launch your phpstorm and notice that everything you wrote was saved but asterisks are gone. So you don't know which files from those opened were changed before you left.

I read few posts here about confusing save functionality and I think this is really not very good how it's currently handled. phpstorm should ask if I want to save these changes or not or at least keep asterisks in tabs after launch so developer will know what file(s) was changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent PhpStorm from automatically saving files on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376431/prevent-phpstorm-from-automatically-saving-files-on-close)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/291434

> "Do not autosave on exit" is strict
>   "won't fix" from the team. You can't
>   have tab asterisks back because file
>   in editor is just loaded from disk and
>   has no unsaved changes. It will have
>   no sense.
>
> If you need to preserve change sets
>   over time you should really
>   considering using source control.
>
> Local git repository will provide you
>   with all the features you need. Just
>   install git, do "Version Control|Git
>   Init" and you have nice changesets,
>   chages in editor, diff on each change
>   and file.

Comment: +1 for source control. Seems like the perfect solution to this. In case the OP doesn't know what it would do, in this case the OP could very quickly and easily see exactly what files have been changed.

Comment: I strongly disagree! Autosave is nice as an OPTION , but users should have a CHOICE.... (I live in the FREE world, not Russia!)

Answer (score 1):

Autosave is an integral part of Jetbrains Platform behavior and can't be disabled.

Comment: Well, you should trust my original comment on product forum http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/291434

Answer (score 1):

In phpStorm 2.0 there is an automatic history that is saved, I guess it's own internal CVS that saves changes between files and specific lines.  You can look at history of the files and restore to an earlier state sort of like windows restore points.

I found the auto save feature annoying too UNTIL I found the history tool in phpStorm and now I don't care if my files are autosaved or not because I can compare all changes to any point in time I want.

Comment: Right, but sometimes, you dont know what you did, or why you did, or when, for what reason you were testing, and no longer no if that change  is senseless or not.. So even if you compare with history, you might not know which changes are "from auto saved" and you really wanted to save, or not.