# Prevent PhpStorm from automatically saving files on close

Tags: phpstorm

When I close a file in PhpStorm, it saves the file automatically.
How can I change it to ask me "Do you want do save the file before closing?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way to disable automatic save completely, but you can [partially control this behavior](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/saving-and-reverting-changes.html):

> Note that those are optional autosave triggers, and you cannot turn off autosave completely.

The answer below from @Owen is not correct, since there is no way to completely turn off automatic save in the IDE.

Automatic save is the core design feature, we believe that it's much more efficient and productive than manual save. There is no way to disable this behavior or enable any confirmations, quoting the [FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-191) (WebStorm is based on IntelliJ IDEA platform, so the same applies):

> Because IntelliJ IDEA has the ability to change so many files
> simultaneously in large refactoring actions, and change them without
> ever opening them, single file saves don't make very much sense. In
> recognition of this, IntelliJ IDEA reserves the right to save any
> of your files literally whenever it wishes. It's actually quite nice
> to never have to worry about your file's save statuses, once you get
> used to it.
>
> "What if I don't like some changes I made, and want to
> roll them back?", I hear you say. Well, for that IntelliJ IDEA
> includes this amazing feature called the [**Local History**](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/local-history.html).
> Every time it saves your files, IntelliJ IDEA actually saves a diff of
> your file from it's previous state, and saves that as well. You can
> see the entire edit history of your files (going back some
> configurable number of days), see the changes you've made, and roll
> back any change. It rules triumphantly, and more than makes up for the
> temporary disorientation caused by lack of single-file save.

This feature has been in IntelliJ IDEA for a decade, and now even Apple has recognized that it's better than manual saving and [implemented it in Mac OS Lion](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202255).

Comment: Thanks for answer. i think this is a dangerous behavior, At lease a config for disable it is necessary. (PhpStorm is best PHP IDE I ever seen.)

Comment: @Reza You can use local history functionality to revert to any previous save -- works fine with such "Save" behaviour.

Comment: I don't like this feature _always_. For example, we were discussing with some colleagues about how a feature should be implemented. Using IntelliJ on one machine, we played with code in many files (like a brainstorm of how the api should look), but they were only ideas, not final code. After the brainstorm these changes were automatically saved by Idea, which was a pain to revert file by file from local history. With another IDE, I'd just have closed the files and chosen not to save changes.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer , even notepad does have "Save changes ?"  question option. This is dictatorial !

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı, notepad is not an IDE that performs refactorings and code changes without opening files, notepad has no local history feature, it's incorrect to compare these products. Most developers love automatic save feature and when working with products that save manually and ask for confirmation, they feel very frustrated. Give it a chance and you'll get used to the automatic save really quickly.

Comment: It's obvious that i didn't compare them in general as you can see above ... The one and only feature i compare is save changes or not freedom. Sure i know notepad is not an IDE (i didn't even say notepad++... native notepad is just a note taker) The right solution should be letting me choose to keep on autosaving or not. That would be fair then.

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı, supporting this option would require changing a lot of product internals that rely on automatic save, while we understand that some users may find it useful, it's not worth the changes to be done in the platform some of which may break the smooth operation in many use cases. When you design the product from the start with the idea of automatic save and many features developed in the last 12 years depend on it, it's simply not feasible adding save confirmations at this point, especially considering that the majority of the users adore the automatic save.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado Relying on the "Do you want to save?" feature is even worse, because you can mistakenly click 'yes'. I think the feature is great. I even have it automatically saving while I type, so I don't need to hit the save button or close the file. What you should be using instead is a Version Control system.

Comment: You have to be kidding me... So say you delete a bunch of code and lose your edit undo/redo history and now you need to close the file and restore the lost code?! No... you're screwed. Better have some source code versioning system in place. Thank God for git. This is a retarded feature, especially for us who ctrl+s constantly while working on a file.

Comment: The autosave is broken in PHPStorm 7.  The saving is not automatic on the Mac.

Comment: I agree with this. You should be using version control anyways. @EdgarVillegasAlvarado , it sounds like a simple 'revert' via git would have saved you guys a lot of trouble.

Comment: Being a IDE/vi user for more than a decade, I still don't like the autosave feature of Intellij. It seems very counter-intuitive for traditional programmers.

Comment: For me the main objection against this feature is that if you use a filewatcher in combination with livereload you are gonna go nuts. I use a filewatcher to transpile Typescript and have grunt setup to livereload. Now on every few keystrokes the Filewatcher triggers which trigger a livereload one grunt detects the changes. When I type one line of code the browser reloads the page about 10 times. Im I look at my browser and I have to wait another 5 times for the reload chain to end before I can test the functionality... Unwanted behavior is an understatement

Comment: I just found out going to the file watcher settings and unchecking 'Immediate file synchronozation' reduces the reload chain. :D

Comment: @CrazyCoder "When you design the product from the start with the idea of automatic save and many features developed in the last 12 years depend on it, it's simply not feasible adding save confirmations at this point".
That is a bad design model. Eclipse does change lots of files automatically when you do refactoring and still live smoothly with Save feature. This explains why IntelliJ is missing another crucial feature: "Save Action" because it would render the product useless since it would need to invoke the actions every second while you are typing!

Comment: This feature breaks the IDE and my application!!  The tmp file written next to the edited file and has no permission to create. As a result the IDE can not write the actual file, EVER -- because the broken file check throws an exception first killing the 100% legitimate edit.

Comment: Another pitfall of this autosave feature is its combination with certain build tools like grunt, which will watch for file modifications and automatically rebuild.  I find the autosave in RubyMine is often so aggressive that I don't even have time to make the few line change I need before the autosave kicks in and my build tool picks up half written lines of code with syntax errors.  I like using both RubyMine and my automated grunt task.  The frequency of the autosaves of a file I am currently editing should be configurable so that I can use both.

Comment: To quote @CrazyCoder, "we believe that it's much more efficient and productive than manual save".  As a product owner, does it really matter what you believe?  Your customers are developers, and every developer will have different beliefs on what is "efficient and productive".  Know your customer - give them the option of configurability.

Comment: I have a few bugs a month _caused_ specifically because of this feature. Maybe I was trying something out and had to take a call and forgot what I was doing and closed the file. Maybe I accidentally typed an extra character while doing a keyboard shortcut and didn't notice. Maybe my kid touched my keyboard. I love everything about PhpStorm _except this awful decision_. My IDE shouldn't be _the cause_ of bugs. And I get tired of people saying use source control - I do, but it doesn't fix the situation where I'm closing a file because I think it's stable or unchanged but it's not. Horrible!

Comment: This is a seriously dangerous bug, another bug that these guys in their infinite wisdom failed to address. The program design team here is purdy rubbish. :(

Answer (score 21):

Autosave settings are under **File | Settings | General**.

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/saving-and-reverting-changes.html

While autosaving is handy for local, non-vital projects, this can be disastrous in a live project, where every change needs to be checked first.

**Update:** In recent versions, they have been moved to **File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings | Synchronization**

Comment: How does this answer to the question?

Comment: @PHPst: It says where the setting is that was asked about.

Comment: I had all of these turned off except saving on frame activation. Even just that one on caused WebStorm to save with every keystroke. Turned it off and problem solved.

Comment: i could not see any kind of these in new version. please suggest.

Comment: @BhavinRana I updated my answer for the new settings dialog.

Comment: i am using mac , and found here : version 8.0.1 : Preferences>System Settings>Synchro>Save files     Thanks. God Bless.

Comment: "Note that those are optional autosave triggers, and you cannot turn off autosave completely." This doesn't answer the question, the files will be saved on close even if you disable all the automatic save options.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents to a similar issue:

I had PhpStorm seemingly auto-save on every keypress, which was making my live reload go mad. Turns out, I had checked `Recompile on changes` under `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript`.

Hope this can help someone.

[image: Screenshot of TypeScript settings in PhpStorm]