# Webstorm: Execute .bat on save

Tags: webstorm

I have a simple bat which merges my .js files into one single file. 
I'd like to execute it every time I save anything in webstorm..
Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible as WebStorm [saves all the files automatically when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377886/104891), there is no trigger to be called on individual file save.

As a workaround you can create a macro that will save all the files and run the external tool, then bind this macro to default Save All shortcut. Now when you save the files via hotkey, IDE will also run your batch script.

Another possible solution would be to use some external service that will watch specified files for changes and run an external tool when they change.

Comment: No need to save all the files in the macro as WebStorm saves all files automatically before running an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using File Watcher.
Go to File | Settings | Tools | File Watchers for Windows and Linux or WebStorm | Preferences | Tools | File Watchers for OS X and click + to add a new tool.