# Webstorm - Run Ant on save

Tags: javascript, xml, ant, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have installed the Ant Debugger plugin in Webstorm and I want it to run the buil.xml everytime I save my changed js files.
For example if I do "Control + S" on the keyboard I want ant to run the xml.
Is this possbible with Webstorm 6.0.2?

Comment: Don't remember what was in v6 .. but check if **File Watchers plugin** is available (should be bundled by default if it is). If yes -- use it -- you can use it to run any external app/script.

Comment: @LazyOne thanky for the comment! i will try this

Comment: @LazyOne do you know how can I set this up ?

Comment: Set up what? File Watcher entry? It's simple: point to program to be executed and what parameters it will use (similar to how External Tools works). The difference is that you can specify what files to watch (via File Type and/or Scope fields) as well as some other small things (like run it only after Save .. or 1 sec after character was typed). **In any case:** http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/ as well as official help pages http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/using-file-watchers.html

Comment: Please note: File Watcher **most likely** will be invoked for **EACH** modified file (so IDE may execute the same task multiple times). If this is not acceptable -- use something different (maybe External Tools). You can then record a macro (execute Save command and then execute that external command) and assign it to the Control+S instead of normal Save.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webstorm: Execute .bat on save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663931/webstorm-execute-bat-on-save)