# IntelliJ IDEA closing unsaved tabs

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, usability

I know that I can mark unsaved files with asterisk if I check the corresponding check box in settings. But when I close the tab IDEA is not asking me "Do you want to save changes?". Tab is just closed and nothing in the project structure is not indicating that I have unsaved file. When I run the application it just saves the file and run the app.

Can I make IntelliJ IDEA to ask me that there is unsaved files in my project that I should now about before launching ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, at least not until [this request is addressed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460).

Use Local History feature, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377886/104891).

Answer (score 2):

I've researched this and it appears that the designers of IntelliJ intentionally block this feature for the most bizarre of reasons, and have been doing so since at least 2012 on this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460 . They refuse to even let you configure the editor to warn on closing unsaved files and give you the choice of saving it or discarding your edits.

*Wow. I'm dumbfounded.*

Sorry for the bad news...I had the same question and am thoroughly disappointed with their answer.

Comment: JetBrains responses and solutions have been the worst of all my IDEs since I started using JB in 2014 (coding for decades).  Find a bug and they reply "if you get enough votes for it we may fix".