# IntelliJ - not asking if I want to save a file

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to the IntelliJ IDE. In the past I was working with Visual Studio or Eclipse.
In those IDEs there was an asterisk `*` above the name of the file which has been modified.

But in IntelliJ with the default configuration **I can't see if the file is modified**. What's more the file is saved automatically when I change focus to another window.

I've found some options under `Settings -> IDE Settings -> General -> Synchronization`:

- `Synchronize files on frame activation`
- `Save files on frame deactivation`
- `Save files automatically if application is idle for...`

After unchecking all that options the file is not saved automatically every time I change focus to another window, which is good. But still I can't:

- see if the file is modified (no asterisk)
- decide if the file should be saved when I'm closing it (IDE doesn't ask for that)

And when I'm closing IntelliJ file which has been modified is saved **without even noticing**.

Do you know what can I do to change how IntelliJ behaves?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/general-2.html

Comment: @Naveen I don't think that helps, Matthew listed this settings above. I'd like to know too how to change those behaviour of Intellij

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7377886/104891

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks.
So it looks like nothing can be done to change this behavior and I need to get used to it..

Answer (score 35):

After unchecking mentioned options go to:

Settings/Editor(IDE Settings)/Editor Tabs:
Check "Mark modified tabs with asterisk"

On 2019.3 Ultimate it's under:

Settings/Editor/General/Editor Tabs:
Mark modified (*)

Answer (score 20):

The exact Save feature like eclipse is not available in IntelliJ.

> Because IntelliJ IDEA has the ability to change so many files
>   simultaneously in large refactoring actions, and change them without
>   ever opening them, single file saves don't make very much sense. In
>   recognition of this, IntelliJ IDEA reserves the right to save any of
>   your files literally whenever it wishes. It's actually quite nice to
>   never have to worry about your file's save statuses, once you get used
>   to it.
>
> "What if I don't like some changes I made, and want to roll them
>   back?", I hear you say. Well, for that IntelliJ IDEA includes this
>   amazing feature called the Local History. Every time it saves your
>   files, IntelliJ IDEA actually saves a diff of your file from it's
>   previous state, and saves that as well. You can see the entire edit
>   history of your files (going back some number of days), see the
>   changes you've made, and roll back any change. It rules triumphantly,
>   and more than makes up for the temporary disorientation caused by lack
>   of single-file save.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206336279/comments/207351939

Comment: Good explanation but the link is outdated. 
This should be the  accepted answer. Adapt yourself to the way the tool behaves.

Comment: @RudyVissers I fundamentally disagree - in a good design a ***tool should be designed for its users*** - the users shouldn't have to adjust to the tool. I also dislike the workflow, I want to control when and how I save my files - I know there's a history I can use to undo the saves - but why add extra steps to undo something I didn't want to have done in the first place?

Comment: I agree @Levon - I would prefer the tool to work how i prefer to work. There is no way i am going to adapt to the fact that a new car i just bought is left handed when i want it to be right handed :)

Comment: @ziggy I stopped using almost immediately once I discovered this, and I am not recommending this to my students or colleagues. Maybe at some point in the future they will give the users more power (via options?) to decide how to use the tool at which point I will reconsider.

Comment: @RudyVissers - I liked the old way too, but I have to say that after a couple weeks, I prefer the IntelliJ way.  Sometimes tool providers need to ask users to drop some of their older ways of thinking in order evolve together to a newer, better place.

Comment: @RudyVissers et al Seemingly canonical link [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206336279/comments/207351939). Back to our regularly scheduled flame-shedding ;)

Comment: This save-less feature is how google docs and some other cloud based tools have been working for years. IntelliJ is ahead of the curve for a desktop tool.

Answer (score 10):

To show an asterisk when a file is modified: open `Settings` (CTRL+ALT+S), switch to `Editor > General > Editor Tabs` and select the `Mark modified tab with asterisk` checkbox.

To remove autosave, uncheck: `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Save files on frame deactivation`