# How to control Save File when I modify a file in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Now I use Android Studio instead of eclipse, I hope I can control if I need to save file, it seems that Android Studio save file automatically.

After I try to close a modified file window, I hope Android Studio can display a prompt dialog and let me choose if save the modified file. How can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Studio is based on the JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA platform which takes full control over when files are saved. The only options for controlling file save are found in the [Appearance & Behavior > System Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/system-settings.html) > Synchronization section of the Settings. These will not do what you require.

Many people switching from alternative IDE's have the same concerns as you. In all discussions I can find there is no way around this.

The JetBrains developers argue that because the platform has built in local history differences for all file saves, it is always possible to rollback any file saves.

Read more from the JetBrains developers here: 
https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-191

Here is a similar discussion on this issue for the IntelliJ IDE:
[IntelliJ - not asking if I want to save a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878226/intellij-not-asking-if-i-want-to-save-a-file)

Comment: Thanks!  I have unchecked all choices in the  Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Synchronization ,  but the system still save file automatically!

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear but it is not possible to prompt to save a file in Android Studio. The IntelliJ platform on which Android Studio is built will always save files without user interaction. There is no way around this.

Comment: Thanks! I maybe open many files in the IDE, sometimes I maybe modifty a correct file unwittingly, and I don't know when and which file I modified, so I hope the system give me a prompt whether save file when I exit Android Studio.

Comment: If you use a version control software (such as git) you can periodically commit your changes at stable places. This makes it easy to roll back as you just checkout a previous commit and work from there (on a new branch in the case of git). At that point though it might be easier to learn the local history built into Android Studio if you don't already use git.