# In Intellij IDEA how do I reload file content's from disk?

Tags: intellij-idea

In vim I can type `:e` and reload a file's contents from disk overwriting any changes I've made. It's a nice way to reset in case I've gotten lost or just want to undo all my changes. This obviously doesn't take into account any kind of refactoring, I just want to nuke all changes to buffer. Not even closing and reopening a tab will work.

How do I do this with Intellij IDEA? I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 13 and I've disabled any kind of auto save.

Comment: related: [Prevent PhpStorm from automatically saving files on close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376431/prevent-phpstorm-from-automatically-saving-files-on-close). (There is not an answer that you are looking for though)

Comment: Look into using a source control management system - svn / git.  If you're using it already, try to check in more often.  Then it becomes a question of reverting your changes via integrated support and shortcut keys you can define.

Comment: I use git, but source control is not back up. I only create commits for finished tasks. Yes you can rebase commits and change history, but that's annoying and a lot of work. You should not have to resort to using git to save file state because your editor likes to cache everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I do in a similar situation:

- Simple - <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Z</kbd> many times to quickly navigate the editing history
- VCS rollback - either for the whole file or for the area being edited (by clicking green areas on the left)
- Local History. Well, yes, for you case it's granularity is not sufficient, so first might be an option

There is also an option to put a label into Local History if you need to rollback to a specific point in time.

For those who use autosave - it is being triggered when code editor loses focus. So doing <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd> during long editing without compiling or running the code makes sense.

Comment: It's amazing to me that reading a file from disk is not easily done. I think I'll make a plugin just to be able to do this. Unbelievable. I'm just going to keep adding bounties to this questions until someone can answer it. :P

Comment: Haha, will this reputation transfer to this question as it has upvotes? Thank you then. :) The thing with Idea is that it is written with having auto-save in mind - this makes very much sense when user applies a refactoring and thus he modifies many files with a couple of clicks. A single action could produce a ton of work. I guess that non-auto-save use cases were not very much tested... so may be sending a feature request to Idea tracker for `Ctrl+Alt+Y` to reload a file from disk when auto-save is off will do the job? @MarkVedder's suggestion is quite intuitive I should say.

Comment: Yes you got the rep, I actually wrote an extension to do what I want, and I marked that as the answer.

Comment: Wow, awesome! I didn't know it's that simple to create a plugin in Idea.

Comment: You should add escapisam's answer to your list. That is the quickest and easiest way to revert a lot of changes (as opposed to hitting `Ctrl+Z` a lot of times or drilling through VCS/Local History).

Answer (score 29):

*File > Synchronize* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>)
It will load the file from the file system. If you have unsaved changes, it will ask if you want to discard them.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have an open file Utils.java. I save it. Type some random text somewhere into the buffer, and then without saving, Synchronize does not revert the text I typed.

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood your use case. I thought you modified the file in an external editor and then came back to IDEA with unsaved changes. Your best bet would probably be to use Local History and do a roll back via it. (Can be accessed via Ctrl+Backquote (at bottom) or _VCS > Local History_) You can also take a look to see if the 3rd Party [IdeaVim](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164?pr=idea) plugin provides the functionality you desire.

Comment: Yeah I looked at local history, but it only saves some changes, not all. Like it would be nice to at least get the set from before the last file save. So weird it can't just reread from file, every other editor I've ever used can do that.

Comment: Local history should be all you need, if it does not work properly, then file an issue.

Comment: *File > Synchronize* does the **opposite**. It actually saves all your changes! I think a better bet than your best bet would be escapisam's answer. That is the quickest and easiest way to revert a lot of changes (as opposed to hitting `Ctrl+Z` a lot of times or drilling through VCS/Local History).

Answer (score 7):

**⌥⌘Y** - Synchronize for Mac users

[image]

Comment: Note that *Synchronize* option is **not the answer**. This does NOT revert your changes, but actually does the opposite: It saves all your changes (in all tabs)! As far as I can tell, there's no functional difference between *Save All* or *Synchronize*.

Comment: Has this changed in newer versions? Synchronize for me will load the disk copy, which was modified by an external formatter, instead of saving my in-memory state.

Answer (score 3):

Open the file in another editor, make an insignificant change and save it. PHPStorm will ask you what to do because the file system and in memory copies of the file have diverged. Click "Load File System Changes".

Note, I was unable to use my undo history as it had become corrupt.

Comment: This is a very neat trick. Looks you don't even need to make changes to the file in another editor. As long as it is `touch`ed, and the timestamp updated, IntelliJ (or any JetBrains IDE) will say that the file is modified and it conflicts with its own version in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since what I want isn't really possible I wrote an extension to do it for me:

https://github.com/btipling/DiskRead/

I'll add it to the Jetbrains plugin repository, it's called "DiskRead".

I wrote a [blog post](http://bjorn.tipling.com/how-to-make-an-intellij-idea-plugin-in-30-minutes) about how I created this if anyone is curious.

Comment: Does the blog post still exist? Link appears to be outdated